# How do I calculate this kind of expressions $(-1)^{-\frac{2}{5}}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

I used a tool and found that it is equal to $0.31 - 0.95i$

Can someone please tell me the way I reach this result step by step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Taking the *[principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value)* of the logarithm we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(-1)^{-\frac{2}{5}}}&=e^{-\frac{2}{5}\mathrm{Log}(-1)}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{2}{5}\left(\ln|-1|+i\mathrm{Arg(-1)}\right)}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{2}{5}\left(0+i\pi\right)}=e^{-\frac{2i\pi}{5}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\doteq0,31-0,95i}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that  $$(-1)^{-2/5}=\frac1{\sqrt[5]{(-1)^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt[5]1}$$ so on the complex plane there will be $5$ solutions.

Write $$1=\cos0+i\sin0$$ and use De Moivre's generalisation formula.

Answer (score 1):

That's only one possible value.

$(-1)^{-\frac 25}$ will be a number $z$ so that $z^5 = (-1)^{-2} = 1$.  $z = 1$ is one such number.  $z = 1$ is the only real such number.  There are four other such complex numbers.

If we view a non-zero complex number, $a + bi$ as a point $(a,b)$ in a plane the point has a distinct distance $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} > 0$ from $(0,0)$.  And the angle between the real axis, the origin, and the point is a distcint angle $\theta$ were $\cos \theta = \frac {a}r$ and $\sin \theta = \frac {b}r$.

So the complex number can be written as $r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$.

And here's the astonishing  thing about it:  If $z = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$ and $w = s(\cos \eta + i\sin \eta)$ then $z\cdot w = rs(\cos(\theta + \eta) + i \sin (\theta + \eta)$.

[Just do the trig:  $z\cdot w = rs(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)(\cos \eta + i\sin \eta)$ and $(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)(\cos \eta + i\sin \eta) = (\cos \theta\cos \theta - \sin \theta\sin \eta)+ i(\sin\theta \cos \eta + \cos \theta \sin \eta)$ and $\cos (\theta + \eta) + i\sin(\theta + \eta) = (\cos \theta\cos \theta - \sin \theta\sin \eta)+ i(\sin\theta \cos \eta + \cos \theta \sin \eta)$]

So that means $z^k = r^k(\cos k\theta + i\sin k \theta)= r^k(\cos k(\theta+ 2m\pi) + i\sin k (\theta+ 2m\pi))$.

And *that* means $z^{\frac 1k} = r^{\frac 1k}(\cos (\frac {\theta}k + m*\frac {2\pi}k) + i\sin (\frac {\theta}k + m*\frac {2\pi}k))$.

So if $z^5 = 1= \cos 0  + i \sin 0$ then $z = \cos {m \frac {2\pi}5} + i \sin{m\frac {2\pi}5}$.

$0.31 - 0.95i\approx \cos \frac {8\pi}5 + i\sin \frac {8\pi}5$.  i.e. the solution when $m = 4$.  The other four are $\cos \frac {2\pi}5 + i\sin \frac {2\pi}5\approx 0.31 + 0.95i$ and $\cos \frac {4\pi}5 + i\sin \frac {4\pi}5 \approx -0.81 + 0.59i$ and $\cos \frac {6\pi}5 + i\sin \frac {6\pi}5 \approx -0.81 - 0.59i$ and $\cos 0 + i\sin 0 =1$

======

When we get comfortable with these ideas we define

$e^{\theta i} :=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta $ (because that satisfies the property that $\frac {d e^z}{d z} = e^z$).

From there we can classify all complex numbers as $r*e^{i\theta}$.  This allows us to derive the famous Euler's identity $e^{\pi i} = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi = -1$.

As $z^5 = 1$ has *five* solutions which do we declare to be *the* fifth root.  Well.... the real root is $1$ of course but as the expressing was $(-1)^{-\frac 25}$ and fractiona powers of negative numbers implies complex roots and for one reason or another the concept of "principal root" and "principal" Logarithms leads to Markus Shauer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use $-1 = e^{i\pi +i2\pi n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Note that we need the factor of unity $e^{i2\pi n}$ in order to discover all solutions:
\begin{align}
(-1)^{-\frac{2}{5}} &= \left(e^{i\pi(1+2 n)}\right)^{-\frac{2}{5}} 
= e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{5}(1+2n)} 
\\
&= \cos\left(-\frac{2\pi}{5}(1+2n)\right) + i \sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}{5}(1+2n)\right)
\\
&= \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}(1+2n)\right) - i \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}(1+2n)\right)
\end{align}

There are only five distinct solutions with $n=0,1,2,3,4$. At $n=5$, the solutions repeat. This is because you have a fifth root. It appears that the $n =0\mod 5$ solution is the one you referenced in your original post.